# Метод split() + RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет! Задача разбить строку '156.75m^2' на массив через регулярку.
Мой код

```
var reg = /(\d+)(\.)?(\d+)?(m)(\^)(2)/,
str = '156.75m^2',
mas = str.split(reg);
```

Работает все хорошо, но почемута первый и последний елемент массива это пустая строка!

```
["", "156", ".", "75", "m", "^", "2", ""]
```

Почему так происходит и как это исправить? Всем спасибо!

Comment: потому что в твоем случае нужен не split, а какой-нибудь match

Comment: При match первый элемент это вся спрока которая была передана ["156.75m^2", "156", ".", "75", "m", "^", "2", index: 0, input: "156.75m^2"] это тоже не подходит.

Comment: `Array.from('156.75m^2'.match(/(\d+)(\.)?(\d+)?(m)(\^)(2)/)).slice(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```js
var reg = /(\d+)(\.)?(\d+)?(m)(\^)(2)/,
str = '156.75m^2',
mas = reg.exec(str);

console.dir(mas);
```

При выполнении RegExp.exec() нулевой элемент всегда исходная строка. Если она не нужна, добавьте mas = mas.slise(1);

Answer (score 2):

`String#split()` разбивает строку по шаблону, т.е. в результирующий массив добавляются подстроки между совпадениями, включая пустые строки в начале/конце и между совпадениями. К тому же, при использовании захватывающих подмасок захваченные подстроки тоже добавляются в конечный массив, что иногда необходимо, но не в данном случае. Тут нужно использовать `String#match` или `RegExp#exec` и удалить первый элемент массива, если совпадение было найдено:

```js
var reg = /(\d+)(\.)?(\d+)?(m)(\^)(2)/;
var str = '156.75m^2';
var mas = reg.exec(str); // Находим первое совпадение
if (mas) {
  mas = mas.slice(1); // Удаляем первый элемент, полное совпадение
}
console.log(mas);
```